# Does any app allow schedule voice record except Cinixsoft recorder?

Tags: applications, audio-recording

I have installed cinixsoft. It can schedule time recording. However, it will randomly stop and then resume. For example, a 2 hour record may cut into 15 mins, 40 mins, 20 mins, 40 min etc. During every cut, it will lost around 3 mins of data. In other words, I will get around 105 mins out of 120 mins of recording. Does any other software do the same thing, but without that problem?

Answer (score 3):

[Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tokasiki.android.voicerecorder) can schedule recording at any given time for a predetermined time.
[image: timer]

Comment: Why is this down voted? It fits the OP's requirements, right?

Comment: @Power-Inside It's a link-only answer.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Link only? He posted the link and _did_ mention about the feature(s), albeit being short.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, I don't think any more addition is required to this answer. Any way screen shot added.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PCMRecorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kohei.android.pcmrecorder). From the app description:

> This is a simple voice recorder. It records by high quality(PCM/WAVE).
>
> Records in 8000,11025, 16000, 22050, 44100 and 48000Hz - 16bits -
> Mono.
>
> Recordings are stored on the SD-card ('PCMRECORDER').
>
> Record:
>
> - Records by background
> - 16bits/Mono
> - Records no time limit
>
> Playback:
>
> - Playback by backgroud
> - Rename
> - Send mail
>
> Settings:
>
> - Sample rate(8000,11025, 16000, 22050, 44100 and 48000Hz)
>
> Permission:
>
> - record audio
> - wake lock (to background recording)